# jemdoc styling does not look right

Tags: jemdoc

I am trying to use jemdoc on my Windows machine to create my first website.

Somehow the styling does not come out right for some reason. I don't get horizontal rulers; the blocks don't show the rectangular boxes with color highlights; multi-level numbered lists don't have the expected labeling change with the levels.

Here is the jemdoc code that I have used.

```
# jemdoc: menu{MENU}{index.html}
= jemdoc -- example page
[https://jemnz.com/ Jacob Mattingley] ([www@jemnz.com])

If the first line of the file starts with +\# jemdoc+, special functions like [menu.html menus] will be used.

== Example
Here are some *text* /features/. I could [http://cvxmod.net/ link somewhere] or insert a raw link to another page like [download.html]. I could use +monospace+, too.

I could write special characters like \#, \$ and \+ by just using a backslash (\\) in front of those characters. Or automatically detect an [www@jemnz.com email address].

~~~
Save the file as +index.jemdoc+, say, and simply call +jemdoc index+ (after [download.html downloading jemdoc], of course).
~~~

Or perhaps a 
. Multilevel
  .. Numbered list
  .. Is more
. Useful?
```

---

Following is index.html code generated by jemdoc.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.1//EN"
  "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml11/DTD/xhtml11.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en">
<head>
<meta name="generator" content="jemdoc, see http://jemdoc.jaboc.net/" />
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="jemdoc.css" type="text/css" />
<title>jemdoc &ndash; example page</title>
</head>
<body>
<table summary="Table for page layout." id="tlayout">
<tr valign="top">
<td id="layout-menu">
<div class="menu-category">jemdoc</div>
<div class="menu-item"><a href="index.html" class="current">home</a></div>
<div class="menu-item"><a href="download.html">download</a></div>
<div class="menu-item"><a href="revision.html">revision&nbsp;history</a></div>
<div class="menu-item"><a href="contact.html">contact</a></div>
<div class="menu-category">user's guide</div>
<div class="menu-item"><a href="cheatsheet.html">cheat&nbsp;sheet</a></div>
<div class="menu-item"><a href="using.html">using</a></div>
<div class="menu-category">goodies</div>
<div class="menu-item"><a href="menu.html">add&nbsp;a&nbsp;menu</a></div>
<div class="menu-item"><a href="stuff.html">other&nbsp;stuff</a></div>
</td>
<td id="layout-content">
<div id="toptitle">
<h1>jemdoc &ndash; example page</h1>
<div id="subtitle"><a href="https://jemnz.com/">Jacob Mattingley</a> (<a href="mailto:www@jemnz.com">www@jemnz.com</a>)</div>
</div>
<p>If the first line of the file starts with <tt># jemdoc</tt>, special functions like <a href="menu.html">menus</a> will be used.</p>
<h2>Example</h2>
<p>Here are some <b>text</b> <i>features</i>. I could <a href="http://cvxmod.net/">link somewhere</a> or insert a raw link to another page like <a href="download.html">download.html</a>. I could use <tt>monospace</tt>, too.</p>
<p>I could write special characters like #, $ and + by just using a backslash (\) in front of those characters. Or automatically detect an <a href="mailto:www@jemnz.com">email address</a>.</p>
<div class="infoblock">
<div class="blockcontent">
<p>Save the file as <tt>index.jemdoc</tt>, say, and simply call <tt>jemdoc index</tt> (after <a href="download.html">downloading jemdoc</a>, of course).</p>
</div></div>
<p>Or perhaps a </p>
<ol>
<li><p>Multilevel</p>
<ol>
<li><p>Numbered list</p>
</li>
<li><p>Is more</p>
</li></ol>
</li>
<li><p>Useful?</p>
</li>
</ol>
<div id="footer">
<div id="footer-text">
Page generated 2016-07-25 13:44:45 India Standard Time, by <a href="http://jemdoc.jaboc.net/">jemdoc</a>.
</div>
</div>
</td>
</tr>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I figured out the answer.

It was a silly mistake. I had placed .css files in a wrong folder.

I moved them to the same folder where index.html file is, and it works fine.